# vue.js data from $.ajax() request not binding to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an $.ajax() function properly working and returning a result and i think i did everything needed for the data binding to go well.

Basically on page load the data from the $.ajax() is appended to a table, but the problem is that the data is not appending like it's supposed to. Am I missing something?

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 overflow-table">
        <table class="table" id="table">
            <thead class="head-color thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th style="border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-left:1px solid transparent;">NAME</th>
                    <th>CLIENT-ID</th>
                    <th>URL</th>
                    <th style="border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-right:1px solid transparent;">ACTIONS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id='table-redirect'>
                <tr class='lightgrey'>
                    <td contenteditable="true">{{ agr.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ agr.client_id }}</td>
                    <td contenteditable="true">{{ agr.url }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/edit.svg"><a href='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/click.php/?id=%3C?php%20echo%20$id;?%3E'><img src="http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/copy.svg"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='lightgrey'>
                    <td contenteditable="true">{{ agr.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ agr.client_id }}</td>
                    <td contenteditable="true">{{ agr.url }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/edit.svg"><a href='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/click.php/?id=%3C?php%20echo%20$id;?%3E'><img src="http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/copy.svg"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='lightgrey'>
                    <td contenteditable="true">{{ agr.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ agr.client_id }}</td>
                    <td contenteditable="true">{{ agr.url }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/edit.svg"><a href='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/click.php/?id=%3C?php%20echo%20$id;?%3E'><img src="http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/copy.svg"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='lightgrey'>
                    <td contenteditable="true">{{ agr.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ agr.client_id }}</td>
                    <td contenteditable="true">{{ agr.url }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/edit.svg"><a href='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/click.php/?id=%3C?php%20echo%20$id;?%3E'><img src="http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/copy.svg"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
    //VARIABLES

    var url = "http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/redirect";
    agr = 0;

    //VUE.JS REDIRECT VIEW MODEL

    var redirect = new Vue({
        el: '#redirect',
        data: {
            agr1: []
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getAll(); //DISPLAY TABLE ON PAGE LOAD
        },
        methods: {
            //
            getAll: function() {
                var self = this;
                console.log('teste');
                $.ajax({
                    url: url + "/getAll",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response); // 
                        self.agr1 = response;
                        console.log(self.agr1);
                        console.log('success!');
                    },
                    error: function() {
                            console.log('error');
                        } //end error function 
                }); //end $.ajax() request 
            }, //end getAll function
        } //end methods
    }) //end vue.js instance
```

Comment: `but the problem is that the data is not appending like it's supposed to` is not enough as a problem description. Please provide the desired result and the result you are getting.

Comment: The table appears empty on page load, when it should be populated when you (re)load.

Comment: Can you tell what kind of response are you getting, is it an array or object or array of objects?

Comment: `(51) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`

Comment: it's printing `{{ agr.name }}` on the table.

Comment: @Timmy what is agr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized a property `arg1` which is an array[ ] in your data property as follows:

```
data: { 
    agr1: [ ] 
}
```

In you ajax cal you are assigning value of `arg1` to response as follows:

```
  self.agr1 = response;
```

So assuming that the response is an array of objects(clients in your case). Since complete information is not provided try this:

```
<tbody id='table-redirect'>
    <tr v-for="arg in arg1" class='lightgrey'>
        <td contenteditable="true">{{ agr.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ agr.client_id }}</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">{{ agr.url }}</td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/edit.svg"><a href='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/click.php/?id=%3C?php%20echo%20$id;?%3E'><img src="http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/copy.svg"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem was related to the controller, but now it's working. (happy?)

Comment: @Timmy I am just telling how stack overflow works. By the way sry if I seemed to be rude.

Comment: well, you were rude and i deleted for a reason. But it's okay. And yes i know 
how Stackoverflow works. And i ask a lot of questions because im new to Vue.js and ajax(), so it's normal i look for help from another people to explain how should I do it correctly.

Comment: @Timmy well then i'll make up to you for being rude by trying to solve your new question.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any help is appreciated. :)